# Receive push message after time of publication with Parse in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using `Parse` to send push messages and everything is works fine. My question is how to user can receive message after the time of publication? E.g: The admin sends a push message, but in the moment of publication the user don't have any network available. After an hour the user have access to a wi-fi network and the pending messages send previously are delivered to the user. What is the parameter to do this or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to worry about the network. Whenever your network will be available, your device will receive the push messages been sent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending a normal push message from parse it's automatically send it to the user whenever the user get back to the network ,

But if you are using `JSON` push , you have to create a receiver   here is  an example I've used it in my project github

[CustomReceiver](https://github.com/tamtom/BAUStudents/blob/master/app/src/main/java/reciver/CustomReciver.java)

and don't forget to declare the receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml`  file,

hope that will work with you